# Magnetic flux of a dipole through a sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law, magnetic-moment, dipole

I wish to calculate the magnetic flux of a dipole placed at the center of a sphere through the sphere. From Gauss's law, I know that it is zero. However, how do I verify it mathematically without using polar coordinates?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use polar coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

The divergence of the magnetic field is zero. This means that magnetic field lines never begin or end. That means the net flux of the field out of any close surface is zero.

Mathematically, we know that
$$\oint \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{A} = \int \nabla \cdot \vec{B}\ dV \ , $$
where $\vec{B}$ is *any* vector field. This is not Gauss's Law, it is [Gauss's divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem), which is a fundamental theorem of vector calculus.

If the divergence of the field $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$, which is one of Maxwell's equations, then it is inevitable that the surface integral on the left hand side must be zero in all situations, including the one in your question.

It is unclear what more (mathematical) proof you need.

In spherical polar coordinates, the magnetic field of a dipole is
$$ \vec{B} = \frac{\mu_0 m \cos \theta}{2\pi r^3} \hat{r} + \frac{\mu_0 m \sin \theta}{4\pi r^3}\hat{\theta}\ , $$
where $m$ is the magnetic dipole moment.

It is reasonably straightforward to integrate this over the surface of a sphere and show that it is zero.
$$ \oint \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{A} = \frac{\mu_0m}{r} \int^{\pi}_{0} \sin\theta\cos\theta \ d\theta = 0 $$

It is obviously much trickier to do in any other coordinate system given the spherical nature of the surface. If your question really is to do this in say Cartesian coordinates then (a) that technical exercise would be a question for Maths Stack Exchange and (b) I'll leave it to someone else.

Comment: How did you integrate that expression?

Comment: @RishiShekher $\sin \theta \cos \theta = 0.5\sin 2\theta$. Then $\int^{\pi}_{0} \sin 2\theta\  d\theta = [-0.5 \cos 2\theta]^{\pi}_0 = 0$.